# Look for text on page, if not found, go next page. Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, svg, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I want to test, if there is a specific text on the webpage using selenium and NUnit.
If the text is present, the test should pass.
If the text is not on the current page, then it should click on the "next page" button, and search on the new page again.

Currently ive got this:

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost:xxxxx/");

if (webDriver.PageSource.Contains("Super Handy"))
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        } else
        {
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//svg[@class=" +
                "'mud-icon-root mud-svg-icon mud-inherit-text mud-icon-size-medium']"));

        }
```

I tried "continue", as it should start the if condition from the beginning.
Tried to find a solution in the past hour, but ended now asking my question here.

Thanks

Comment: I found a work around for my old question.

First i wanted to use the paging buttons, which switch to next/previous sites if there are several sites. The problem is here, that the buttons are generated automatically and its not so easy to find the element for it.

But recently we have a search field implemented, with which i can filter out datas i need. So no paging needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath will not work this way.
Try this:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[name()='svg' and @class='mud-icon-root mud-svg-icon mud-inherit-text mud-icon-size-medium']"));
```

Comment: Hm actually i used this method non stop in the past lines and they worked.

The question here is more, how can i make the if condition start from the beginning when the condition is not true :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to start from the beginning there?

Comment: Im adding data to a list. And the list has different pages which are being filled with new data. And i want to backcheck if the data, i added to the list, is present in the list. With this method, i do also want to test, if the button for the next pages works. It should simply start the if condition over and over again until it finds the data and calls "Assert.Pass();

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
while(webDriver.PageSource!=null){
    if(webDriver.PageSource.contains("your text")){
          Assert.Pass();
       }else{
        webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[name()='svg' and @class='mud-icon-root mud-svg-icon mud-inherit-text mud-icon-size-medium']")).Click();
        //Can add wait time for the page to load completely here
        Console.WriteLine(webDriver.Title);
        continue;
       }
}
```